# js .click() not working in if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am having is inside my if statements, the .clicks() do not work. I need i button to be clicked and rerun the script but it isnt working.  The SetTimeout(start,5000) helps it repeate but makes the script run several times at once.

```
document.getElementById('sound-toggle').onclick = function() {

    var startingBet = 5;
    startingBet = parseFloat(startingBet);



    document.getElementById('bet-bt').onclick = function () {
            function start() {

            //show if it is getting chip amount
            //var rr = document.getElementById('bet-rb-2').innerHTML; //neerdsa classs s3elec5to9r
            //var rr = document.getElementById('bet-rb-2').innerHTML; 
            //

              setTimeout(start,5000);

            //select the result of the spin
            var result = document.getElementById('result-text').innerHTML;
            alert(result.length);
            if (result.length == 5) { //lost


                alert('lost');
                 //document.getElementById("bet-bt").click();
                break;
            } else if ( result.length == 4) {  //won
                alert('won');
                //document.getElementById("bet-bt").click();
                break;
            } else { 
                alert('something is wrong' );
                ///document.getElementById("bet-bt").click(); 
                break;
            }
        }
        start();
    };
};
```

Comment: you are declaring start() function twice?

Comment: Please make working fiddle of this and let us know

Comment: sorry i somehow pasted the same piece twice. it is correct now, still need advice on the click problem though

Comment: @Regent well it still might be called event handler. I just want to make clear that it is not attached multiple times. I also would highly suggest not to use `onclick=""` in production code.

Comment: how can you use break without any loop.

Comment: @t.niese it didn't deserve to be called event handler :) But yes, it is. I just don't name it so to avoid messing with normal `addEventListener`. Well, I highly suggest not to use `onclick=""` anywhere...

Comment: @suchit probably it was something like this: you look how `switch-case` works, then use `if-else` instead, but either forgot to remove `break` or simply didn't understand what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be try something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sound-toggle').click(function(){ 


    var startingBet = 5;
    startingBet = parseFloat(startingBet);

    });

     $('#bet-bt').click(function(){ 

         setTimeout(start,50);
       });
});

function start() {

    //show if it is getting chip amount
    //var rr = document.getElementById('bet-rb-2').innerHTML; //neerdsa classs s3elec5to9r
    //var rr = document.getElementById('bet-rb-2').innerHTML; 
    //



    //select the result of the spin
    var result = document.getElementById('result-text').innerHTML;
    alert(result.length);
    if (result.length == 5) { //lost


        alert('lost');

    } else if ( result.length == 4) {  //won
        alert('won');
        //document.getElementById("bet-bt").click();

    } else { 
        alert('something is wrong' );
        ///document.getElementById("bet-bt").click(); 

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou!  this is working, jsut had to edit a few lines for make it happen. This part of my script is working perfectly now.  I should have known this, but ive been coding for near 12 hours straight and my brain is fried...  thanks you again